# Printing (with lpr) works from command line, but not from Java

Tags: java, printing

So, first things first, we cannot use the `javax` print services because it is extremely slow as we have more than 20,000 printers installed on a machine (the lookup uses lpstat which is incredibly slow). So, we're using lpr.

When I do this:

```
cat myfile.pdf | lpr -P "MyPrinter"
```

it prints the file perfectly to the printer name `MyPrinter`. To do the same in Java, I'm doing this:

```
cmd = String.format("lpr -P \"%s\"", "MyPrinter");

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();

/*
 This essentially runs a thread which reads from a stream and
 outputs it to the STDOUT. This is what I've written to help with
 debugging
*/
StreamRedirect inRed = new StreamRedirect(p.getInputStream(), "IN");
StreamRedirect erRed = new StreamRedirect(p.getErrorStream(), "ER");

inRed.start();
erRed.start();


/*
 This is where I write to lprs STDIN. `document` is an InputStream
*/

final byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
int len;

while((len = document.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}

out.flush();
out.close();
```

But, I get the following error:

```
SR[ER]>>lpr: The printer or class was not found.
```

Here, `SR[ER]` is just a custom label that is prefixed by the `StreamRedirect`. Why is this happening? Why is it able to find a printer when I run it from my command line, but not otherwise?

Also, I tried to run `whoami` from within the Java program and it says that I am running it as the same user I am logged in as (the same user with which I execute `lpr` on the command line).

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the command and the arguments in a string array

```
String[] cmd = new String[] { "lpr" , "-P", "MyPrinter" };

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

You might also want to use the newer [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class.

Comment: I'll try that, but I don't quite get how that would make any difference?

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked. (Can't accept as answer right now.. will do in 2 minutes)

Comment: @RohanPrabhu: did you check the API documentation? It says pretty clearly that arguments to `.exec(cmd)` need to be given as a string array, i.e. if you command has arguments they should be in an array

Comment: @RohanPrabhu See the javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html, depending on your requirements you have to choose from the different (overloaded) exec methods.

Comment: @posdef: Well I guess that was my bad :(

Comment: no problem, just keep in mind, when in doubt start by looking at the javadocs :)

Answer (score 0):

`cups-bsd` includes `lpr` which is made to be used with Java.

Be sure to execute `apt-get remove lpr` and `apt-get install cups-bsd`.